# Find the number of integer solutions of $|x|+|y| \le 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

> Find the solutions of $|x|+|y| \le 10$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

**My solution**:

$$|x|+|y|+z=10$$

Now the solutions if there were no absolute values is:

$$\binom{13-1}{10}=\frac{11*12}{2}=66$$

now subtract that once that have $0$ then multiply the others by $4$ and  multiply that ones that only has $1$ zeroes by $2$.I get $221$ Am I right?

Comment: Do you want the solutions, or the _number_ of solutions?

Comment: @Arthur number of the solutions.

Comment: i would start with $$x=-10,y=0$$ or $$x=-9,y=-1$$ or $$x=-9,y=0$$ or $$x=-9,y=1$$ and so on

Comment: are you interested on all solutions?

Comment: There is a nice graphical approach. $|x| + |y| \le 10$ describes the interior of a square with vertices $(0,\pm10), (\pm10,0)$. Simply shade in the integer points $(x,y)$ lying within this square.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner  No I just want to check my answer that is true or wrong?

Comment: Yes, the answer is 221.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of integer solutions of $|x|+|y|\le n$ is 
$$1+4n+4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k=2n(n+1)+1.$$
$1$ is for the origin, $4n$ is for the points on the 4 semi-axis,
and finally $4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$ counts the points in the 4 right triangles inside the 4 quadrants.

See also the Sloane' sequence https://oeis.org/A001844

Answer (score 2):

[Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) says that the area of a polygon whose vertices have integer coordinates is given by

$$A=I+{B\over2}-1$$

where $I$ is the number of *Interior* points with integer coordinates and $B$ is the number of *Boundary* points with integer coordinates.  For the given problem the polygon is a square with diagonals of length $20$, so $A=200$.  The bounday points satisfy $|x|+|y|=10$, so it's easy to see that $B=40$, hence $I=200-{40\over2}+1=181$.  The number we want is

$$I+B=181+40=221$$